# NullReferenceException when changing XML element attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception, isolatedstorage

this is my method to change XML element attribute value:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    XDocument xml = null;
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Stats_file.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
       xml = XDocument.Load(isoFileStream, LoadOptions.None);
       xml.Element("statrecords").SetElementValue("value", "2"); //nullreferenceexception
    }
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoFileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("Stats_file.xml", FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
       xml.Save(isoFileStream, SaveOptions.None);
    }
}
```

In 7th line i have NullReferenceException. Do you know how to change value without error?

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<stats>
    <statmoney index='1' value='0' alt='all money' />
    <statrecords index='2' value='0' alt='all completed records' />
</stats>
```

Comment: does "statrecords" exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `xml.Element()` in this case you get the root element. So you should use the [`Descendants()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb353813.aspx) and the [`SetAttributeValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue.aspx) methods:

```
var elements = xml.Descendants( "stats" ).Elements( "statrecords" ).ToList(); 
//becuase you can have multiple statrecords
elements[0].SetAttributeValue("value", "2" );
```

Comment: I have this error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'

Comment: Thanks for reply bu check this: http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/1996/errorgl.png

Comment: This means that there is no elements in the list. I tested my code and it works, so are you sure you're loading the right xml file and that it contains that node?

Comment: I have changed 'statrecords' element and 'statmoney' element both to 'stat', and in code chenged to 'elements[1]'. Thanks for help, it works :)

Comment: There's no need to use `Descendants` here, or `Elements`. Using `xml.Root.Element` *should* work fine (and it's simpler), if the XML is as shown in the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two probelms.

The reason you're getting a `NullReferenceException` is that `xml.Element("statrecords")` will try to find a *root* element called `statrecords`, whereas the root element is called `stats`.

The second problem is that you're trying to set an *element* value, whereas you want to change an *attribute* value, so you should use [`SetAttributeValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue.aspx).

I think you want:

```
xml.Root.Element("statrecords").SetAttributeValue("value", 2);
```

EDIT: The code I've given works fine with the sample XML you've provided. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        xml.Root.Element("statrecords").SetAttributeValue("value", 2);
        Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
<stats>
  <statmoney index="1" value="0" alt="all money" />
  <statrecords index="2" value="2" alt="all completed records" />
</stats>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is still make exception. If you know some other method to change this value, please share with me :)

Comment: @ŁukaszWróblewski: "It still make exception" isn't nearly enough detail to help you. What exception? Where? Can you post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem? How much diagnosis have you performed?